# Not able to scrape the Linkdin search peoples results in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping, linkedin-api, mechanize

I am working on Ruby and Rails Application where I need to scrape the search people results from LinkedIn.

I am using the mechanize gem for scraping.

```
require 'mechanize'
require 'rubygems'

agent = Mechanize.new
agent.follow_meta_refresh = true
login_page = agent.get("https://www.linkedin.com/login?fromSignIn=true&trk=guest_homepage-basic_nav-header-signin")
login_form = login_page.form
login_form.session_key = "username"
login_form.session_password = "password"

search_page = agent.submit(login_form, login_form.buttons.first)
search_page = agent.get("https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/all/?keywords=anand&origin=GLOBAL_SEARCH_HEADER")
```

I am able to login to LinkedIn using above script but when I am hitting the

```
search_page = agent.get("https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/all/?keywords=anand&origin=GLOBAL_SEARCH_HEADER")
```

it is not giving the search people results. Giving the below response.

```
  #<Mechanize::Page
  {url
  #<URI::HTTPS https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/all/?keywords=anand&origin=GLOBAL_SEARCH_HEADER>}
  {meta_refresh}
  {title "LinkedIn"}
  {iframes}
  {frames}
  {links
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "LinkedIn" "/feed/">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "LinkedIn领英" "/feed/">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "Home" "/feed/">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "My Network" "/mynetwork/">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "Jobs" "/jobs/">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "Messaging" "/messaging/">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "Notifications" "/notifications/">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "Try Premium for free" "#">}
  {forms
  #<Mechanize::Form
   {name nil}
   {method "GET"}
   {action
    "https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/all/?keywords=anand&origin=GLOBAL_SEARCH_HEADER"}
   {fields}
   {radiobuttons}
   {checkboxes}
   {file_uploads}
   {buttons}>}>
```

As you can see in the above response header links are coming but not showing the search results data.

Is there any other way so that I can scrape the LinkedIn search people data ?

Comment: It looks to me like LinkedIn has a [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authentication). Why do you want to scrap the HTML webpage?

Comment: @spickermann I did not find any of the API for search people results. Also my requirements are very similar to https://phantombuster.com there user needs to give search results URL in the input.

Comment: I don't think you would be able to get it using ruby. Linkdin and alike social media site optimize their site by loading and rendering data as needed. So there will be lot of javascript backed rendering data on screen which mechanize is not capable of capture. In such case you should used JS based solutions like puppeteer(Node.js)/phantomjs/sellenium etc.

Comment: @AmitPatel I have tried using selenium chrome driver and able to scrap data. The issue while using selenium I was getting that always open the browser and always gave the first five profiles when I run the query to get names of profiles like driver.find_elements(xpath: "//a[@data-control-name='search_srp_result']").

Comment: The search results on webpage shows me 10 results. So ideally you should get 10. If you look at the page, you will find pagination control at the bottom. You should write script to click on Next link until it gets disable. Clicking on next will get you another 10 records which you will scrape again in the same session.